# How to resize VirtualBox window

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, dkms

I know this has been asked in other places but im having some issues
I have installed dkms x11 all off that but auto-size guest display is still grayed out
My machine has 32mb of video ram reserved but still after restart nothing

Comment: See [my answer to another question here](http://askubuntu.com/a/247786/3940) where I linked to other relevant posts. Basically all you need is the [guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox).

Comment: i have already installed the additions... when i go to install them again it says they are installed and up to date

Answer (score 0):

For auto-resize to work, you also need to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions.

Comment: aren't those it? dkms and things?