# Ubuntu 17.10 (on VirtualBox) suddenly changed resolution to 800x600

Tags: screen, display-resolution

After some weeks of working full resolution, now I get 800x600. I didn't change any settings, so it have to be a bug. Another problem is, that I can't change it back to 1920x1080. The dialog in settings is cut at the right (I can choose bigger resolution in dialog, but I don't know what are buttons on right (Apply/ok/Cancel ...)). 
1. Can I change resolution with command line? I tried some suggestions, but it looks that 17.10 doesn't have the same technique.
2. Why is this happening so often in Ubuntu? There are many questions (for different versions, GUIs ...) where users fall into this problem. This is (rare) thing where Windows are better :-)

Comment: older computers sometimes are not supported or if the configuration is very prime.  its a difficult problem.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/12618/3940 or https://askubuntu.com/a/247786/3940

Comment: Tnx to all.
This is simple solution which works for me: https://kacnje.blogspot.si/2017/11/ubuntu-on-virtualbox-screen-resolution.html