# Not able to view all options in Ubuntu desktop

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I am not able to view all the options in Ubuntu desktop - scaled or windows mode.

Also, I am not able to find the setting to do same.

How to do it? I want all options to be view or there should be scroll bar to do the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What options are you missing? Have you install VBox Guest Additions>?

Comment: In the screen shots, are options on the right are getting cut, and options which are on extreme right are not visible. No, I have not installed anything apart from basic installation which I did. Do I need to install VBox Guest Addition for better interface ??

Comment: Yes, install the guest additions. Click device then insert guest additions. Then open the disk by clicking on it in the sidebar and then click run this program in the bar on nautilus.

Comment: Is it something I need to do in my VirtualBox app or in Ubuntu desktop ?? In either case I am not able to see the device option to do same ?? Some quick help before I do Google, please ..

Comment: I just told you exactly what to do. In Virtualbox Click Devices then "Insert Guest Additions CD image". In Ubuntu (inside the virtualbox) you will see a disk image, at the side, above the bin. Click it and it will open. Then you will see a button, at the top of the window that just opened that says "Run this software". Then click it, and click "run in terminal".

Comment: Sorry, but I really cannot find it. I am using VBox 4.3.  I have added VBox image in my original question.

Comment: Devices. In the top bar, next to View. When you are looking at the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Your second screen shot indicates that the guest additions graphics driver was not installed correctly. You may need to re-install them. With HOST + A you will adjust the Ubuntu desktop to the windows size. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/23053/resizable-screen-mode-for-virtualbox-behaves-strange-with-ubuntu-as-guest

Comment: @Tim Thanks a lot. It is resolved. If you may want to put it as an answer, I will accept it. +1'ed already. Thank you.

Comment: @Takkat  +1'ed already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in comments:

> Install the guest additions. Click `Devices` in the top bar and then `Insert Guest Additions CD image`. A CD will appear in Ubuntu Click it and it will open. Then you will see a button, at the top of the window that just opened that says "Run this software". Then click it, and click "run in terminal.